# forEach on iOS Safari won't work

Tags: javascript, ios, loops, foreach, safari

I have a function that allow me to load specific modules in specific pages based on their body classes. For some reason my forEach function won't work on iOS devices, specifcaly on safari. I am trying to solve this problem for a while, and I do not know how to preceed... Using try/catch, the given error is:

**TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.forEach is not a function. (In 'document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.forEach(function(e){var t=e;x.hasOwnProperty(t)&&new x[t]})', 'document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.forEach' is undefined)**

Here is my code:

```
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Shelf from './Components/Shelf';

import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Category from './Pages/Category';
import Product from './Pages/Product';
import NossasLojas from './Pages/NossasLojas';
import Checkout from './Pages/Checkout';

const Routes = {
    "home": Home,
    "single-product": Product,
    "page-template-nossas-lojas": NossasLojas,
    "archive": Category,
    "woocommerce-cart": Checkout
};

export default class Pages {
    constructor(){
        new Header();
        new Shelf();

        try {
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.forEach(function(e){
                let pageName = e;

                if(Routes.hasOwnProperty(pageName)){
                    new Routes[pageName]();
                }
            })  
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot! **:)**

Comment: `classList` is not really an array,  as such `forEach` is not guaranteed to be part of it.  Just use `for of` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class list isn't an array, it is an object.

What you can do is convert it to an array using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like this:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList).forEach(i => console.log(i))
```

Comment: For those who wants copy and paste:

Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList).forEach(function(e) {
   let pageName = e;

   if(Routes.hasOwnProperty(pageName)){
    new Routes[pageName]();
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

`Array.from` is fine, but to save creating an array, you can use `for of`,    this saves creating an additional array.

Another big win for `for of` is when you start to do a lot of `async` code,  you can use `await` with `for of`, but unfortunately there is no `async forEach`.. (yet)..

```js
for (const e of document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].classList) console.log(e);
```

```html
<div class="one two three"></div>
```

Comment: I tried with no success. Same problem: works on pc, but not on iOS. The answer above worked though.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `for of` certainly works with iOS -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of   I've a feeling you had another error.